# Can a manager reduce my work hours because there has been (unverified) issues with a coworker?

Tags: employment, canada, british-columbia

I am having a conflict with a coworker. Without going into the nature of the conflict, the manager wants to schedule us on separate days. However this would mean a reduction in the hours I work in a week.

Can a manager unilaterally reduce an employees hours for this reason?
Can she offer the ultimatum "work with him or have your hours reduced"?

Here is a previous [law question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/67617/i-am-stuck-working-alone-with-new-coworker-who-i-believe-is-dangerous-must-the) and [workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/174612/manager-wants-to-reduce-my-hours-so-i-dont-work-with-a-coworker-im-not-getting)

Comment: What is the nature of your contract? Are you contracted to work n hours and would be expected to work less than that?

Comment: For the purposes of the question, did you ask not to work with said coworker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a manager reduce my work hours because there has been (unverified) issues with a coworker?

No. This sounds in violation of [section 83(1) of the BC Standards Employment Act](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/00_96113_01#section83) and [section 2.8 of the BC Occupational Health and Safety Regulation](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/296_97_01#section2.8). Your situation altogether reflects the employer's awareness that "*a complaint or investigation may be [...] under [the Standards Employment] Act*"  for the employer's failure to properly address the issues the coworker is causing.

This is another reason why you really should not acquiesce on the requested statement about you being "satisfied" with the manager's resolution. Complying with the manager's request will give her the opportunity to falsely allege that your statement was in reference to her "resolution" or settlement/agreement as to a reduction of your work hours and that you belatedly "changed" your mind.

> Can she offer the ultimatum "work with him or have your hours reduced"?

She can make a *proposal* of that sort. However, positing it as *ultimatum* contravenes the statutes I mentioned in [the other answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/67620/18505) insofar as the employer knowingly is penalizing you unless you forcibly take undue risks which are the employer's responsibility to address.

Comment: In situations like this is there anything I can preemptive do, or must I wait for the employer to break the law by reducing my hours and then sue them in court? Is there a government agency or something I can involve, like the labour board?

Comment: @user127275 If you already have evidence that the employer has essentially threatened with the reduction of hours or that reduction is imminent, you may file a complaint. See sections 74 *et seq* of the Employment Standards Act and sections 48 *et seq* of the [Workers Compensation Act](https://www.bclaws.gov.bc.ca/civix/document/id/complete/statreg/19001_02). The agency you need to contact is the [Employment Standards Branch](https://www2.gov.bc.ca/gov/content/employment-business/employment-standards-advice/employment-standards/contact-us) and/or the Workers' Compensation Board of BC.